# How to identify and display difference between values in two rows of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am stuck in this problem.

Table

```
EID(primary key)  CID    Col1    Col2    Col3 ... 200 columns like this...
   1                3      5000   'ABC'  1200                  
   2                4      5000   'DEF'  1000                 
   3                3      5500   'ABC'  1300                    
   4                3      5000   'XYZ'  1100                  
   5                4      8000   'DEF'  1000                    
   6                3      4000   'ABC'   600
```

How can i display the difference in values between two latest rows with same CID (In this case it will be rows with Eid 6 and Eid 4) with the name of the columns.Thanks in advance. I am using MS-Sql Server 2008.

Comment: _"200 columns like this"_ create a table with at least two columns: `EID` and `Value`, `EID` is the foreign-key to this table. Then insert one record for every column. That process is called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and will save your life ;)

Comment: What about column 2 where Text value is there? Which one you want to keep?

Comment: @TimSchmelter :- I agree. But i guess at this point i can't change the schema.

Comment: @Bikash Pradhan:- I dont want to update any column. I only want to display the name of the column and values present in them for two rows who have same   value in CID column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`lag()` window function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx).  For example:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  EID
        ,       CID
        ,       col1
        ,       lag (col1) over (partition by CID order by EID) as prev_col1
        ,       max(EID) over (partition by CID) as max_eid_per_cid
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
 where  col1 <> prev_col1 -- Col1 must have changed
        and EID = max_eid_per_cid -- Only latest EID per CID
 order by
        CID
```

Comment: Did you see `MS-Sql Server 2008` ?

Comment: @bummi: Didn't see that, and `lag()` is only available in 2012 and higher

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Using  `Window function` u can get the last two values. and by using `left join` u can compare current row with previous row.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER ( partition BY cid ORDER BY eid DESC) rn,
                *
         FROM   #tt)
SELECT a.eid,a.cid,a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,
       ( a.col1 - b.col1 ) col1_diff,
       ( a.col3 - b.col3 ) col3_diff
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN cte b
              ON a.rn = b.rn + 1
                 AND a.CID = b.CID
WHERE  a.rn IN ( 1, 2 )
```

Comment: Not sure if difference equals subtraction in this context.  And how does your query filter the two latest rows with the same CID?

Comment: @Andomar I have used order by Eid. since in question it is clearly mentioned that for `cid 3` , `eid 4 and 6` were latest